# Multiple validation directives not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write my own set of directives. I have written following two directives:

- eaValidateEmail (Validates the format of the email address)
- eaValidateUnique (Will validate the uniqueness by a call to a rest service once complete)

**What I want to achieve:**

- First the eaValidateEmail directive is executed which returns false until the format of the email is correct
- Then and only then the eaValidateUnique directive should execute and check if the email address is taken already over a rest service. If the value is not found it will return true, else it will return false.

**What's happening**

When I only add the eaValidateEmail directive, everything is working and the format of the email is validated.

But as soon I add the eaValidateUnique directive then the eaValidateEmail directive is left out and the ctrl.$valid method of the eaValidateUnique directive is always passing even though ctrl.$valid is false in console.log.

I have read through the AngularJS documentation, bought two books but the examples are always very basic. Currently I can't figure out where the problem could be located. It looks like there is a clash with ngModelController but I can't figure out the right way to solve this issue.

I'm currently testing with the ValidateCtrlNew form. So the field in the "New" section of the html form.

**Questions:**

- Does anybody know how to write the directives so that they are executed in serial order as I add them as attributes to the input element?
- How can I prevent such clashes with directives? Isolated scope is also no option for multiple directives.

Here is the ***jsfiddle***: http://jsfiddle.net/charms/6j3U8/230/

```
<div ng-controller="ValidateCtrlNew">
    <form name="user_form_new" class="pure-form" novalidate>
        <fieldset>    
            <legend>New</legend>
            <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="txt_fld" ng-required="true"  ea-validate-email ea-validate-unique/><br/>
            <div class="inv_msg" ng-show="user_form_new.email.$dirty && user_form_new.email.$invalid">Invalid:
                <span ng-show="user_form_new.email.$error.required">Please enter your email.</span>
                <span ng-show="user_form_new.email.$error.eaValidateEmail">This is not a valid email.</span>
                <span ng-show="user_form_new.email.$error.eaValidateEmailCheck">Checking email....</span>
                <span ng-show="user_form_new.email.$error.eaValidateUnique">This email is already taken.</span>
            </div>                
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>


.directive('eaValidateUnique', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                console.log(ctrl);
                //ctrl.$setValidity('eaValidateUnique', true);
                if(ctrl.$valid) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('eaValidateUnique', false);
                    console.log("valid was true");
                }                    
            });
        }
    };
}])
.directive('eaValidateEmail', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                // set validity to true to clear out if previous validators fail
                ctrl.$setValidity('eaValidateEmail', true);
                if(ctrl.$valid) {
                    // set validity to false as we need to check the value here
                    ctrl.$setValidity('eaValidateEmail', false);
                    if(viewValue !== undefined && viewValue !== "" && EMAIL_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                        // if the format of the email is valid then we set validity to true
                        ctrl.$setValidity('eaValidateEmail', true);
                        ctrl.$setValidity('eaValidateEmailCheck', true);
                        console.log("TRUE");
                    } else {
                        // if the format of the email is invalid we set validity to false
                        ctrl.$setValidity('eaValidateEmail', false);
                        ctrl.$setValidity('eaValidateEmailCheck', true);
                        console.log("FALSE");
                    }    
                }
                return viewValue;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add priority to eaValidateEmail to 100 like..

```
restrict: 'A',
 priority:'100',
    require: 'ngModel',
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that the validators are chained on the $parsers array. AngularJs validators return the value if the validator decides the value if valid, but return an undefined if the value is invalid.

This way, the other validators on your chain would not have a value to work with anymore.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers